# Flow text around an image in (GitHub) Markdown

Tags: github, markdown

I have a narrow long image that I want to display at the top right of a README.md file on GitHub. I have been trying several things to get it aligned right and currently have

```
<p align="right">
  <img src="doc/subpagelist.png" />
</p>
```

This works in that the image is aligned on the right side, though is rather useless as all content that is below in image in the Markdown file gets displayed under the bottom of the image, rather then to the left of it.

Is there a way to have the text flow around the image (without getting rid of headers and paragraphs)?

Answer (score 127):

The `align="right"` (or `left`) attribute works in GitHub Markdown:

```
<img align="right" src="doc/subpagelist.png">
```

Comment: Doesn't work with headers though. How do I align an image next to a header?

Comment: Excellent ! Many thanks, I've been looking a lot for this... Works also on Gitlab :)

Comment: @minseong I think the best you can do is `# <img align="center" src="https://github.com/YourCompany/YourProject/blob/master/res/Logo.png"> YourProject`, but text is not really "centered", sadly.

Comment: @minseong To put an image next to a headline, put the right-aligned image *before* the headline, with a blank line in between.

Comment: Is there anyway to `clear: both` after the image? The image I'm using is fairly tall and it's bleeding into the next H1 section.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter you need to use e.g. `<br clear="right"/>`. Using `style="clear: both"` doesn't work for the same reason `style="float: right"` doesn't: the `style` attributes are stripped out.

Comment: @waldyrious YESSSSSS! You are a genius, sir or madam! Works like a bloody charm! Thanks for sharing. Using it here: https://github.com/joshuapinter/react-native-unified-contacts/blob/master/README.md#select-a-single-contact

Comment: Has this recently broken for anyone else? I had used this answer ages ago and it worked, but just noticed text was no longer floating correctly. I tried various alignments and it appears to strip them all and always left align the image + not allow text to start until after the image :(

Comment: Is there a way to align multiple images on the left or right (in a column fashion) and the text on the opposite side?

Answer (score 15):

`align="left"` works fine. To break the alignment again, use a `<br clear="left"/>` (or `<br clear="right"/>`) tag:

```html
<img src="/path/to/image.png" align="left" width="200px"/>
some text floating around the image

<br clear="left"/>

A "newline". This text doesn't float anymore, is left-aligned.
```

Comment: Also, if you want a clean margin just add  style="margin:16px;"

Comment: In GitLab, `<br clear="left"/>` doesn't work for me.
*(not belonging to the original question though)*

Answer (score 8):

It works for me (*only for jekyll, it does not work for Github markdown*):
Put the code below in your content markdown (I have put it on the first line for better organization)

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .image-left {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      float: right;
    }
    </style>
```

And refers to your image as follows:
`[![Proguard](./proguard-snippets.png)](http://www.thiengo.com.br/proguard-android){: .image-left } Your Text comes here...`

Note the *.image-left* class besides the image url.

The final results are here: [Movies of the Year jekyll github page](https://richardsilveira.github.io/MoviesOfTheYear/)

Comment: Should the CSS line be ' float: left;' instead of 'float: right;' for shifting to the left?

Comment: About: "only for jekyll, it does not work for Github markdown"? Explanation: set up GitPages and look at `<user>.github.io/<name>.io`, not `github.com/<user>/<name>.io`

Answer (score 6):

In markdown you can add extra attributes to tags. For instance I use this for what you intend to do:

```
![Some Title](http://placehold.it/image.jpeg){:style="float: right;margin-right: 7px;margin-top: 7px;"}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with github flavored markdown.

Comment: nor does this work in my Azure DevOps private Git repository (which, of course, [may very well be github.com](https://itsfoss.com/microsoft-github/) under the covers now)

Comment: That's because github is feverishly dropping any styles. See https://github.com/github/markup

Answer (score -1):

What you are describing is "floating" of an image, which allows text to flow around it. There are a [number](http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101) of [good](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/) [turtorials](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) about floating in CSS if you want to learn more about this topic. In the mean time, to get an image to float in Markdown you can wrap the image in a div and float that div using:

```
<div style="float: right">
    ![Replace this with your image](http://placehold.it/85x85 "Title")
</div>
```

Comment: The div remains, but Github strips out any included style information.

Comment: I've not tried it in GitHub, but that works like a charm in  Azure DevOps Markdown.